# Issues installing Nvidia drivers in Debian 9

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia

I'm new to linux and I decided to install Debian 9, I installed it in my HDD in UEFI mode with a USB stick and the DVD 1 iso found here: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/bt-dvd/. I had some issues with network drivers but I managed to solve them. Then I wanted to install Nvidia propietary drivers, my laptop is a MSI GL62-7RDX which comes with an i7-7700HQ CPU and a GTX 1050 (2GB) graphics card, I followed the steps specified here: https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_9_.22Stretch.22 which are:

- Add non-free repositories by modifying the sources.list file.
- Execute the following commands as root:

  ```
  apt update
  apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's/[^-]*-[^-]*-//') nvidia-driver
  ```
- Reboot

The problem is that when I rebooted I only got a black screen with a blinking cursor. I decided to follow the steps shown here: https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Backing_out_in_case_of_failure in order to throw back the changes. After rebooting I could see the login screen, but when I tried to login I got a login loop, despite of the password being correct.

I also tried to install Nvidia drivers as shown here: [How to install the latest NVIDIA drivers on Debian 9 Stretch Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-debian-9-stretch-linux#h3-1-debian-packages)  but I got black screen with blinking cursor again.

**In summary,** I would like to know how to properly install Nvidia drivers in my laptop. I think I am missing something and that the problem is related to my specific hardware, because a few days ago I tried to install Ubuntu 17.10 and it only worked if I added *nomodeset* by pressing e in the GRUB.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with your problem but I just thought I'd say, “welcome to [unix.se]”. It’s a pleasure to see someone’s first question being so well researched and such care taken to write their question so that it’s clear what the problem is. Hope you get a good answer.

Comment: Thnak you very much @AnthonyGeoghegan

Comment: Reinstalling whole system would be my advice.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue the first time I tried to install Nvidia driver.

If you're on a laptop you have Optimus (hybrid) graphics. You had to install "bumblebee-nvidia" to install the Nvidia driver. It was stated on the page you used to install the driver.

https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Identification

> Note: if this lspci command returns more than one line of output, you
>   have an Optimus (hybrid) graphics chipset, and the instructions on
>   this page do not apply to you. Check the Bumblebee page instead.